# How to create a datablock for a list of numbers as input?

Tags: fast-ai

Each instance of my data is a fixed length of signal reads. I can not find any information on how to pass this into a learner. I imagine something ala.

```
Learner(data, labels, ...)
```

where data[i] is the signal for labels[i].

Do I need to store the data in a CSV file and then load it using pd.read_csv(), or is there another more convenient way to do this?